# how much deposit?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Dictionaries typically say the noun deposit is countable, but a Google search shows there are some instances of "how much deposit" on some British and Australian sites.

Do you think it's natural to say "How much deposit do you have to pay for a mortgage?"

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: In AmE the question is usually *What's the required downpayment?* or *How much is the deposit?*  But I do see examples of *How much deposit do you need for ...?*  A would-be renter could ask a landlord *How much security deposit do you require?*

Comment: You can also say: How much of a deposit do you have to make on a mortgage.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly acceptable to say "How much deposit".  The reason why is because when you're referring to "deposits", you're referring to several payments or instalments.  So while deposit *can* be countable, it is also very much an amount as well.

This allows both sentences to be equally valid:

> "How many deposits do you have to make?"
>
> "How much was that deposit?"

On a subtler note, while it's not incorrect, it may be more natural to say something like: "How much do you pay on your mortgage?"